# Why does this ID generating code make a KeyError: -1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder, keyerror

A problem in this part of my code causes KeyError: -1

Do any of you know what might cause this?

```
for i in range(len(B130317)):
    if B130317['LON'][i] != B130317['LON'][i-1]:
        currentID += 1
    newID.append(currentID)
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `if` statement in the first iteration. You are trying to access `i - 1`, and on the first iteration `i` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the comments of @Badgy:

```
for i in range(1,len(B130317)):
    if B130317['LON'][i] != B130317['LON'][i-1]:
        currentID += 1
    newID.append(currentID)
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(B130317)-1):
    if B130317['LON'][i] != B130317['LON'][i+1]:
        currentID += 1
    newID.append(currentID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `B130317['LON']` is an empty list, `B130317['LON'][i-1]` for `i=0` will throw `KeyError: -1` exception. 
I don't know what is your business logic but maybe you should consider changing the loop to be:

```
for i in range(len(B130317['LON'])):
# your logic
```

Comment: You're right with this, thanks for the correction. It didn't solve the problem, but it is good :)